# Swipe View from left to right and vice versa in Android

Tags: android, animation, swipe, slide, gesture

I have an icon which is located at the right of the screen, i gave it a -25dp margin so its not fully visible, i want the user to be able to move the button while touching it until it is totally viewed and return it back to its position.
I tried many code such as the below but i cannot figure what is the correct value for the swiping for each screen resolution, can anyone help me with a better solution[image].

```
    class DragExperimentTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public DragExperimentTouchListener(float initalX, float initialY) {
        lastX = initalX;
        lastY = initialY;
    }

    boolean isDragging = false;
    float lastX;
    float lastY;
    float deltaX;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {


        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(arg1)) {
            // single tap
            return true;
        } else {
            // your code for move and drag


            int action = arg1.getAction();

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !isDragging) {
                isDragging = true;
                deltaX = arg1.getX();
                return true;
            } else if (isDragging) {
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {


                    if (arg0.getX() >= ??) {
                        arg0.setX(arg0.getX() + arg1.getX() - deltaX);
                        arg0.setY(arg0.getY());
                    }
                    return false;
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    isDragging = false;
                    lastX = arg1.getX();
                    lastY = arg1.getY();


                    return false;
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    arg0.setX(lastX);
                    arg0.setY(lastY);

                    isDragging = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to move it anywhere on the screen or just x or y axis ?

Comment: x-axis , until the image is fully visible to the user

Comment: from right to left , then the user can return it back

Comment: Your movement working ? only density issue ? which is screen end ?

Comment: i can move it from right to left in a horizontal view but i cannot guess when the image is fully viewed to the user so he cannot swipe more.

Comment: There is something you can do i haven't tried it yet. But first you can get the size of the screen which gives you pixel x & y and you can then guess the center point of the imageview and calculate if its right and screen max width is same .. something like that,